# Sorting Input from Multiple HIDs in Windows

Tags: python, mongodb, windows-7, barcode-scanner, hid

I have found a number of answers in pulling information from HIDs in Linux, but not many in Windows.

I have created a system where a person can scan an ID badge when entering a briefing that logs their attendance into a database.  It utilizes a Python 3.4 front end which queries and then updates a MongoDB database.

Currently, I have a USB Barcode Scanner which, when scanning, acts as a keyboard and "types" what the barcode says, followed by a CR.  I also have a window which takes the text input and then closes the window and executes a database query and update when the CR is received.

The current issue is speed.  I have been asked to expand the system so that one computer with a USB hub can take 4-8 of these Barcode Scanners at the same time, attempting to increase scanning rate to 1000 people every 5 minutes.

What I am afraid will happen is that if two scans happen at almost the same time, then their inputs will overlap, generating an invalid query and resulting in both individuals not being logged.

As far as I can understand, I need to place each Scanner in its own thread to prevent overlapping data, and I do not want to "lock" input from the other scanners when the system detects a scan beginning as this system is all about speed.  However, I am unsure of how to differentiate the devices and how to implement the system.

Any solutions would be appreciated!  Please take note that I am unfamiliar with HID use in this sense, and only have a basic background in multi-threading.

Comment: what kind of scanner do you have? and do system need to have response like OK/NOK after scanning?

Comment: The currently used scanner is from Amazon: [link](https://www.amazon.com/Automatic-Barcode-Scanning-Bar-code-Adjustable/dp/B00406YZGK/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1467243673&sr=8-3&keywords=barcode+scanner)

The system does not need a response, and we may be upgrading to better scanners soon.  They will still be of the variety that acts as a keyboard and then adds a CR when it is done scanning.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario I will suggest using scanners/readers that can emulate serial (COM) port. As HID device writes to same bus then there is a huge probability that output from two or more devices could by mixed-up.

More over I will add a device id string to a prefix like `dev01`. Binding to a com port can be used by pySerial module.

Any comments welcome!

Comment: Much appreciated!  Apologies on the delayed reply, government internet can be fickle like that.  I assume I should run a thread for each device to continually monitor each?  Also, would it be possible to take a device that automatically installs (plug-and-play style) drivers to act as a COM port?  Thank you so much for your help!